# Load a file that has nonstandard delimiter into pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a file that looks like below, where the fields are delimited by '?':

```
(01-01-2011-04:43:50?2521795691802591407?94.20.58.165?
```

When i use

```
mac = load 'Activity_1295336_01-01-2011.log.gz'using PigStorage('?');
```

I still cannot access the inner fields, for example `mac$1`.

Comment: ? is  reserved for params I guess try changing the delimiter to check

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected on my side...

```
$> pig --version
Apache Pig version 0.9.2-cdh4.0.0 (rexported) 
compiled Jun 04 2012, 17:42:27

$> cat temp1
01-01-2011-04:43:50?2521795691802591407?94.20.58.165?

grunt> a = load '/temp1' using PigStorage('?') as (datetime, id, ip); 
grunt> dump a;
grunt> >> (01-01-2011-04:43:50,2521795691802591407,94.20.58.165,)
grunt> b = foreach a { funky = CONCAT(ip, '_-* FUNKY'); generate datetime, id, funky;}
grunt> dump b;
grunt> >> (01-01-2011-04:43:50,2521795691802591407,94.20.58.165_-* FUNKY)
```